# script: Log both output and exit codes

Tags: bash, scripting

The `script` command logs an entire shell session to file. This is great, but when reviewing the session I'd like to be able to see the exit code of each command that I ran.

Is it possible to capture this in the `script` logs? Ideally without displaying it to the user of the `script` session, but that would be acceptable if necessary.

Example of running script:

```
me:~ oliverlade$ script
Script started, output file is typescript
bash-3.2$ echo "hello"
hello
bash-3.2$ true
bash-3.2$ false
bash-3.2$ exit
exit

Script done, output file is typescript
```

The contents of the log file:

```
me:~ oliverlade$ cat typescript
Script started on Sun Aug  7 13:02:43 2016
bash-3.2$ echo "hello"
hello
bash-3.2$ true
bash-3.2$ false
bash-3.2$ exit
exit

Script done on Sun Aug  7 13:03:03 2016
```

What I'd like it to be:

```
me:~ oliverlade$ cat typescript
Script started on Sun Aug  7 13:02:43 2016
bash-3.2$ echo "hello"
hello
(exit 0)
bash-3.2$ true
(exit 0)
bash-3.2$ false
(exit 1)
bash-3.2$ exit
exit

Script done on Sun Aug  7 13:03:03 2016
```

Answer (score 2):

From the `script` man pages:

```
-e, --return
```

"Return  the  exit code of the child process.  Uses the same format as bash termination on signal termination exit code is 128+n." I misinterpreted this...

If you need to use `script`, it seems as though the best way to see the last exit code would be to add it in your shell prompt. It's not a bad idea to do this anyways.

Comment: it gives me `script: invalid option -- 'e'`

Comment: @Rahul exactly what command did you type? 'script -e' or 'script --return' should work on Linux. What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using debian squeeze. I tried both commands both gives me same error.

Comment: @Rahul quite strange, here is the debian man pages for script: https://goo.gl/6h7Dzy , you can see the options there. I recommend adding the exit code to your bash prompt. This way, it will be logged, and you can see it in the shell as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may incorporate the exit status of the last executed command (`$?`) in your primary prompt (`PS1`).

One example:

```
$ PS1='$? \$ '
0 $
```

Testing it:

```
0 $ false
1 $
```

You have to use single quotes to avoid expanding `$?` at the time of assignment to `PS1`.  You should not `export` the prompt variable.

Another example:

```
$ PS1=$'(exit $?)\n$ '
(exit 0)
$
```

Testing that:

```
(exit 0)
$ false
(exit 1)
$
```

Comment: it should be incorporated in `script`